# Including Poco C++ Libraries into Qt Quick Application (Qt Creator) on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, poco

I have some issues and trouble building my Qt project including Poco C++ libraries.

I successfully compiled Poco like described in their [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html#8) using Terminal and `make` instead of `gmake` with the following configuration (Configured for Darwin):

`./configure --omit=Data/ODBC,Data/MySQL --no-tests --no-samples --static`

After executing `make -s install` the library (.a and .dylib) and header files are located in `/usr/local`and `/usr/local/include/Poco`.

Then I created a new Qt Quick Application (using Qt Creator) and edited the .pro file of my project with following lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L"/usr/local/lib" -lPocoFoundationd -lPocoJSONd -lPocoNetd -lPocoUtild -lPocoXMLd
LIBS += -L"/usr/local/lib" -lPocoFoundation -lPocoJSON -lPocoNet -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML
```

When using Poco in the main.cpp file of my Qt project, e.g. `Poco::Path`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "Poco/Path.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    Poco::Path p(true); // path will be absolute
    p.setNode("VMS001");

    return app.exec();
}
```

it doesn't build. The header file is found, autocompletion works, too. But I got two errors:

```
:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
:-1: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also tried other configurations compiling Poco, used the "Add Library..." dialog of Qt Creator and copied the header and library files into my project directory (and changed the path in the .pro file of course). Hope anybody could help me out or created also a Qt project using Poco on OS X and it works ;-)

Finally some environment infos:

- Qt Creator 3.3.2 (opensource)
- Based on Qt 5.4.1 (Clang 6.0 (Apple), 64 bit)
- OS X Version: 10.10.2
- Poco C++ (Basic Edition) Version: 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

While writing this post I came up with the following idea: Is C++11 enabled in my project? Seemingly, nope. So I added

```
# Enables C++11. Qt 5+ required
CONFIG += c++11
```

to my .pro file and voilà, it works!